# android paypal payment gateway integration issue

Tags: android, paypal

Android implemented pay-pal payment gateway integration in my app but i have

one problem with that I am unable to view pay-with card button it only shows me the pay-with pay-pal button with pay pal account.

imported PayPalAndroidSDK-2.13.1.aars file

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':PayPalAndroidSDK-2.13.1')
}
```

and also added a dependency in gradle file

can some one help to resolve these issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true
}
dependencies {
   compile('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1')

}
```

Please change the dependency and default configuration